# how can I set cakephp array indexing with this structure?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

My Field Value is :

```
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][][fault_name]" value='+c[0]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][][unit_cost]" value='+c[1]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][][unit_price]" value='+c[2]+'></td>';
'<td><button onclick="removeTR('+i+')" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></td>';

[JobFault] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => sectionPart
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [unit_cost] => 22
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [unit_price] => 21
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => IC3277
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [unit_cost] => 22
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [unit_price] => 22
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => IC54444
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [unit_cost] => 33
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [unit_price] => 33
                )

            [creator_id] => 2
            [centerId] => 1
        )
```

But I want in this way...........

```
[JobFault] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => sectionPart,
                    [unit_cost] => 22,
                    [unit_price] => 21
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => sectionPart,
                    [unit_cost] => 22,
                    [unit_price] => 21                    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fault_name] => sectionPart,
                    [unit_cost] => 22,
                    [unit_price] => 21                   
                )


            [creator_id] => 2
            [centerId] => 1
        )
```

Comment: Please refer [Hash Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) for CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][0][fault_name]" value='+c[0]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][0][unit_cost]" value='+c[1]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][0][unit_price]" value='+c[2]+'></td>';

'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][1][fault_name]" value='+c[0]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][1][unit_cost]" value='+c[1]+'></td>';
'<td><input type="text" name="data[JobFault][1][unit_price]" value='+c[2]+'></td>';
```

And so on using increments of 1, the form helper would be like such

```
echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.0.fault_name');
echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.0.unit_cost');
echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.0.unit_price');

echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.1.fault_name');
echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.1.unit_cost');
echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.1.unit_price');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i m ok with you , and add echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.creator_id'); , echo $this->Form->input('JobFault.centerId');